# How to stop/start multiple instance of jboss applications using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

We have 3 instance of jboss application running on a Linux server. each instance has a separate start and stop script.

How to execute all 3 at once and also one instance at a time (like stop instance B only)

Answer (score 1):

Stopping all instances:

```
- hosts: yourHost
  remote_user: yourUser
  become: True

  tasks:
  - name: (shutdown-servcies) Stop service
    service: name="{{ item }}"
             state=stopped
    with_items:
      - "{{ jbos1 }}"
      - "{{ jbos2 }}"
      - "{{ jbos3 }}"
```

For stopping only once I'd rather recommend to run ansible command with an extra-vars like `ansible-playbook... YourPlaybook.yml --extra-vars "service_to_stop=jbosX"`

```
- hosts: yourHost
  remote_user: yourUser
  become: True

  tasks:
  - name: (shutdown-oneService) Stop service
    service: name="{{ item }}"
             state=stopped
    with_items:
      - "{{ service_to_stop }}"`
```

Ansible will run the command as sudo, although you can change the user and avoid running with sudo.